# How to split and reuse Typescript types?

Tags: typescript

There are two types:

```
type Car = {
  brand: string
  model: string;
  firstRegistration?: number;
}

type Color = "red" | "blue" | "green";
```

How can I create new type `OtherCar` that has `brand` type from `Car` together with `Color` type?

What I have tried:

```
type OtherCar = {
  brand: Pick<Car, 'brand'>;
  color: Color;
}

function makeCar({ brand, color }: OtherCar): string {
  return `${brand}, ${color}`
}
```

When calling

```
makeCar({ brand: 'Opel', color: 'red' });
```

There is an error - TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type `Pick<Car, "brand">`.

Comment: The type Pick<Car, "brand"> means "the same thing as the type Car, but only with the brand property). So it's equivalent to `{
  brand: string; }`. It seems you just want a string. So use string, not Pick<Car, "brand">

Comment: What if I need to do it in a DRY way? If `brand` changes from `string` to something else, then I would need to update the type it two places. What would be the right way to reference the type from the `Car`?

Comment: See the answer of ford04. Or extract a common interface (Brandable) and extend it.

Comment: `makeCar({ brand: { brand: 'Opel' }, color: 'red' });` This will work cause `brand` in `OtherCar` is an object of Car but just with `brand` property.

Answer (score 1):

You have nested `brand` property one level too deep, try out the [following](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=17&ssc=67&pln=13&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgJygXigbwLACgq6gIwTgDsATALigGdgEBLYgc2zygFsB7UiAG0pvpMA3CzwAzOghoAlCIzoC4wOh2IB%20SsQCubfBAQisAX2zZQkWBx4ckqAEQIIpO1AA%20UO-h5aIL93cZHCGI7QzNwaAB5YAALfXhbdFFcAGMrG0oYdINsIygAMigABToUgGsAHgSAGigAckISUjqAPlMsMS1iFOVVdjgyiASACjQCIjJatOskI0pouIQEgEp%20WgZGJJw8R2AtBGIoAAMAEjRGsiNas%20mbIyPc9rTiGihHKhR%20wZGxi4p6yKQHh1KbZSh1RzNKBGZZCKAAenhUEBvFqkKAA) instead:

```
type OtherCar = {
    color: Color;
} & Pick<Car, 'brand'>

const res = makeCar({ brand: 'Opel', color: 'red' }); // Opel, red
```

Edit: Your `OtherCar` [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) type in the question looks like this, which is not what you want:

```
type OtherCar = {
    brand: {
        brand: string;
    };
    color: Color;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Works great!

Comment: `type OtherCar = { brand: Car['brand'], color: Color };` also works.